# lack of files after generating APK

Tags: react-native

I am building an app , my app contains a folder called content that folder contains a menu.html file that is calling some js, css files

- content (size 5 MG)
- menu.html

  - css
  - js
  - images

my problem is that after having generated my apk , installed it on my mobile
it displays first screen , when i click to move to next screen (the screen that is calling menu.html)  here it sucks , i get a simple empty screen !

my question should I import manually this content folder to my android assets folder ? should I remove the 2 existing files in assets index.android.bundle and index.android.bundle.meta ?

Comment: I do not fully understand how are you planning to use html files in react-native project? React Native's components are same ones you would use in native development for phone, not html as you would for web.

Comment: why not ? there is a webview i am calling a file my menu.html , no problem there, on emulator it works great

Comment: Ye sure if you'r going to use webview. I might just want to avoid doing that since you do not get as good user experience as you would with native components in performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

You could try linking it. Since `rnpm` is part of RN you don't need to install anything, just add an entry in your `package.json`

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "./path/to/file.html"
  ]
}
```

and then run `react-native link`

If you're already using `rnpm` you can add another path separated by a comma to that assets array. I don't know for certain but I would imagine the react-native is going to by default ignore HTML files unless they are explicitly linked.

You could also manually store the file in your Android assets folder and require it from there, but this won't work for iOS so if you're going cross platform I would try to get it to work via `link`.

Also as a side note, WebView kind of sucks. For a better user experience I would suggest rewriting the contents of that file in a way that react-native can render them.

Comment: thanks for ur help Robbie it didn't work , some RN troubleshoots are real nightmares

Comment: then I would try manually putting it in `android/app/src/main/assets`